# Get Latitude and Longitude from SQLite database for use in Android MapOverlay

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-maps, mapactivity

If I store the Latitude and Longitude of a bunch of locations in a SQLite Database, how would I retrieve these values and place them each in an OverlayItem class for use in Google's Map code?

Database name: `database`

Table name: `place`

Fields in `place` Table:

- `id`
- `title`
- `description`
- `latitude`
- `longitude`

How do I get the latitude and longitude data of each location and add it to an ArrayList itemOverlay?

Do you have any ideas or an example? Thanks you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to do a query like this:

```
SELECT title, description, latitude, longitude
FROM place
```

Which can be done in Android like this:

```
    /* 
       databaseObject = YourDbHelper#getReadableDatabase();
    */
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Cursor locationCursor = databaseObject.query("place", new String[]{
            "title", "description", "latitude", "longitude"}, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    locationCursor.moveToFirst();

    do {
        String title = locationCursor.String(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("title"));
        String description = locationCursor.String(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("description"));
        int latitude = (int) (locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("latitude")) * 1E6);
        int longitude = (int) (locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("longitude")) * 1E6);

        items.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), title,
                description));
    } while (locationCursor.moveToNext());
```

You need to multiply the values by 1E6 because Android uses an integer representation of the lat/long values.  If you already took care of this when populating the database, skip the multiplication and use `locationCursor.getInt(...)`.

Comment: A possibly slightly more efficient approach would be to hand the `Cursor` to the `ItemizedOverlay` and have it implement `size()` (returning `getCount()` from the `Cursor`) and `getItem()` (returning the result of creating an `OverlayItem` from the `Cursor` after a `moveToPosition()` call). This saves keeping your own `ArrayList`. But your approach would work as well, and would be particularly important if the `Cursor` might be closed while the map was still in use.

Comment: I agree Mark. I debated posting that code, but the user seems to be lost on even getting data out of the database, so this generic code seemed to be a better choice.  Once they figure out what I did here, they should be able to refactor the code into `getItem()`.  You're also right that the posted code would be better if you had data that was static, no reason to keep an open `Cursor` around in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. However i don't get the exactly point on map what i want..i don't know why. The pins move to the next city and the distance between each other extend 2 or 3 times

This is and example i store in my database type String
latitude = 18.481941 longitude = 98.551844  ... which i miss? anyway, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Sorry for stupid question.. i already know the cause .. i put the wrong latitude and longitude :b

Comment: @April you complete this type of demo then give me i also need you.