# Add overlay on stored Latitude and Longitude in a SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-maps

I have store the Latitude and Longitude of locations in a SQLite Database, how would I retrieve these values and place them each in an OverlayItem class for use in Google's Map code?
i got this question with answer
[1]: [Get Latitude and Longitude from SQLite database for use in Android MapOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286746/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-sqlite-database-for-use-in-android-mapoverlay) this is really helpful but im new in android unable to understand many things e.g  where i should perform this action, in class that is extends **MapActivity** or in **ItemizedOverlay** please would anyone explain it step by step it will be highly helpful for all learners. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement ItemizedOverlay within the MapActivity class. see example.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.drawable.navup);      

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

// Get your GeoPoints from SQLLite and use them below for Longitude and Latitude

GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude); 
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "City", "State");
List<Overlay> mapOverlays1 = mapView.getOverlays();
Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin);
ClevelItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay1 = new ClevelItemizedOverlay(drawable1, this);
```